# Literally Nothing is Working to Change the Colour of My Gedit Embedded Terminal

Tags: command-line, gedit

I know several people have asked here about how to change the colour of the embedded Gedit terminal, and I've thoroughly read those posts myself. I've tried everything, but mine is still white.
I am sick of it and really really want a solution that works. Some solutions I have found suggest clearing the palette settings in dconf-editor to do so, but mine is not letting me do that. Can you please help? It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

but mine looks like this:

[image]

and is giving me an error message when I try to clear the palette
I am using Gedit 3.18 on an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. My gconf-editor is also faulty in that and it does not show all apps, but I don't know if that's contributing to the problem.
I really don't know what to do, and I'm so very frustrated. I love Gedit as I'm a beginner in Ubuntu and I want to continue using it to code in C++, but this embedded terminal issue is making me consider getting another text editor.
Please help me!